# Is it possible to make python into an executable file?

Tags: python, executable

Is there a way to make python an executable file on a mac, windows, or unix?
Nothing fancy in a GUI, but open a terminal window or a console window and run like somebody executed the application through terminal.

If there's no easy way to do this, can someone direct me to any reading material? Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you trying to create an app from code already written? Check out [p2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) or [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PyInstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/), there is also py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/).

My experiences with PyInstaller on Linux show that it tends to place a lot of shared libs which may sometimes clash with your distribution so it's sometimes necessary to trim it down a bit afterwards.